# ops-class.org setup error: 'mips-harvard-os161-gcc: not found'

Tags: compiler-errors, operating-system, kernel, cross-compiling, bmake

I'm trying to set up the kernal for ops-class.org course. After configuring DUMBVM kernel, when I run 'bmake depend', I get this error. I've installed all the tools from here- http://www.os161.org/resources/setup.html . I'm now stuck at this step- https://ops-class.org/asst/0/#_build_your_os161_kernel